# Button is always aligned to the right

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I took the code straight from bootstrap's website yet the button is always aligned to the right. After going through all the view templates and css I was able to find the culprit. The issue I believe comes from `Site.css` which comes by default in an MVC web application. When I comment it out, the search bar expands to connect with the Go button

[image: Search bar issue]

**This is the snippet of css that causes the issue:**

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

**My code is as follows:**

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                    </span>
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

This is an example of my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/5wczeuf7/2/

Why is this like this by default? How do I resolve it?

Comment: How does it cause the issue?

Comment: I am not sure but if I comment that part then the search bar connects to the Go button (the search bar becomes bigger)

Comment: Inspect this button in developer tools and I am sure you will find out the reason. It doesn't make sense to me that `max-width` is causing this issue.

Comment: Please show css for `.input-group-btn` and button itself.

Comment: the css hasn't been modified, it is from `bootstrap.css` here is my problem in fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/5wczeuf7/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent div of that button made it go to the right, I fixed it by removing the width from the parent div:

```
.input-group-addon, .input-group-btn {
    width: 0;
}
```

If you don't want to affect everything, but just one, you will have to add a custom class, or id to the parent div.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12246/

Comment: No problem! Keep in mind this affects all other objects with that bootstrap classes, so you might only apply it to that div. Good luck.